# ServiceStack Response - Change encoding?

Tags: xml, soap, utf-8, character-encoding, servicestack

I've only just started using ServiceStack and because of a few legacy systems I need to keep SOAP support. I am having an issue though with a non-Windows system that is calling my new service through SOAP due to the encoding of the response being UTF-8.

Is there a way to change the default encoding for the response? Can it be done just to the SOAP response? Even though the XML header on the SOAP response does say <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> my non-Windows, old old old client does not support UTF-8 and it has problems with the leading byte order mark which I'd like to remove.

Thanks!